# How to create tabs like in Mail app?

Tags: ios, user-interface

How to create tabs like in Mail app? Here's screenshot

[image]

Comment: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/create-segmented-control-ios7

Comment: @CodeLღver How is this question a duplicate of that question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Its segmented controll. Check object libary in interface builder. PLay with it and ask question if you find any problem

[Segmented Controls](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html)

Comment: select your xib or storyboard . I have attached an image . You can search seg and drag that to your view